# Google Play Console - Crash Report: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, runtimeexception, android-9.0-pie

I received some crash reports from users of one of my apps in the Google Play Store.

This is the stack that I find the play store:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2946)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3081)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1831)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6806)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

And this is the device: `Xiaomi POCO F1 (beryllium), Android 9`, the app crash on start up.

Unfortunately there isn't any reference to my package on the stack.

This is my gradle settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

In the other devices with android 9 where I tested there are no problems. Could it be a problem related to the play service present in the device?
Some idea?

Thanks

Comment: The reason for this is that the Android team and Google simply do not care about crashes, delivering a reliable OS or helping devs or app owners. It's a mentality issue that will never change with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about Android is it is open source. So you can investigate these issues for yourself.

In this case, let's look at the source for ActivityThread. Do a Google search for ["source ActivityThread.java"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=source+ActivityThread.java). For me the top result is [the source code on android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java).

Now look at the performLaunchActivity() method. It's a shame there is no message in the stack trace, but it looks like this method throws a RuntimeException when there is a problem loading the launch activity for your app. So it looks like some sort of message is coming in, your launch activity is trying to start, but throwing an exception on loading your app. Unfortunately, I can't give you much more detail than that.

You might want to try integrating with a solution like [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/) which gives you more detailed tools for investigating crashes than the Play Console offers.

Comment: Thanks, i look at the source code and I discovered that the crash depends to a class that i use via reflection.
Good idea intregrate Firebase Crashlytics. Thanks

Comment: What if the device manufacturer has changed the code under that class to their liking? This is useful only on devices with stock Android.