# java.lang.RuntimeException in Google Play - no idea how to analyze

Tags: android, kotlin, runtimeexception

I got via google play the following crash report:

```
Android 9

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3364)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3548)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2155)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:109)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7539)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

I'm using Kotlin - none of the given line numbers (?) seem to make sense to me! Is there a place to see the generated java source?
Does anyone has an idea, how I can get a clue out of it, what is going on with my App? ( Of course I tried to test, but do not get the error simulated/repeated.) It looks to me, as it crashes when it tries to launch a new activity - but how get more details?

Any help is very much appreciated!

I'm using this code:

```
fun startTrainer(view: View) {
    println("$TAGconst start Trainer ")
    val intent = Intent(this,Trainer::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: You can check this question. You will find a answer. [stackoverflow.com/questions/53853213](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853213/google-play-console-crash-report-java-lang-runtimeexception)

Comment: thx for the link, but my knowledge is not good enough to understand the source code from activity.start - as suggested.Do you have any other idea what I can do?